# How can I use a variable of flask in jinja while writing href

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

**#html code**

```
<a href="/dashboard/{{ name }}"> click here </a>
```

**flask code**

```
@app.route('/dashboard/<name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def text():
     user = "abc"
     return render_template('dashboard.html', name=user)
```

on clicking 'click here' i want to route to dashboard/abc

Comment: I want to change href in html in order to run flask code

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dashboard/')
@app.route('/dashboard/<name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def text():
     user = "abc"
     return render_template('dashboard.html', name=user)

@app.route('/dashboard/abs')
def something():
  return 'redirected'
```

just add `@app.route('/dashboard/')`

Note: I've also included an additional `@app.route('/dashboard/abs')` decorator just to display you're redirected.

Comment: what should i write in html?? <a href="/dasboard/{{ variable name}}"</a>?? Is this correct??